# How synchronize the container folder to local empty folder when container running

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like run a container with links my container folder to my local folder. I can create a link the local folder to container folder, if the container folder isn't empty, he's overwritten.

But I would like a reverse link : if I run a image with `docker run` the folder in container writes in my local folder his data, and if I modify the files in local, the changments are writte in container.

I ask that because I download a framework online in my `Dockerfile`, and if I start a new project with this image, I would like the framework are directly download from container without having to download manually before.

It's possible ?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use volumes that will be mapped to your container:

```
docker run -it -v <my_local_folder>:<my_container_folder>
```

Comment: But if you run the container with this command, the folder in the container are rewritten by the empty local folder... and the container folder will be empty...

Comment: I am not sure it is possible. you can try to just docker cp the content to the host

Comment: You can use a command to copy a file in the container to local ?